# how to stop matlab from running a script in mac

Tags: matlab

I know this is a duplicate but none of the answers published already are solving my problem . im using mac and trying to stop matlab runing with cmd + .
or cmd + c . pressing for long time does not help . 
any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl + C? Some heavy Matlab calls may be un-interuptable in this way, but mostly this should work.

Comment: Ctrl + C works on Mac... unless you are running a MEX function.  If that's the case, without proper planning, the only way you can stop MATLAB from running is to kill the program... and of course you lose any work you had before you ran the script.

Comment: my problem is that the curser was not on the cmd .. oops

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about the intermediate results or the content of your global workspace, you could always [kill MATLAB's process](https://superuser.com/questions/192219/is-there-a-way-to-list-and-kill-running-processes-on-mac-os-x-in-a-windows-ctrl).

Next time you'll run a script with huge loops, [take the advice](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/stop-execution.html) of including some function calls that will transfer briefly the control to the user interface: `drawnow`, `getframe` etc.

Comment: i read the kill matlab's proccess ctr + C does not work . what is the break button in mac?? also cmd + . does not work

Comment: @user2993422, Ctrl-C doesn't kill the process. Follow the link.

Comment: @user2993422 To explain the difference: CTRL + C is asking MATLAB to stop the script for you. Killing the process is asking the operating system to  stop MATLAB for you.

Answer (score 0):

For Octave 4.4.1 GUI, on MacOS 10.14 Mojave, to exit code mid execution I use:

For code that is paused:

> option + c

For code stuck in a loop:

> control + c

You may need to hold this down for a few seconds

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! It would seem this is something the author of the question already tried, as mentioned in the question itself. Truth be told, the question is vague and hard to answer. It could be that your answer is exactly what the author was looking for, but I think that is somewhat unlikely in the current state of this (3 year old) question. Still, thank you for your contribution.